# Flink Streaming: Unexpected charaters in serialized String messages

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-producer-api, flink-streaming

My stream is producing records of type `Tuple2<String,String>`

`.toString()` output `(usr12345,{"_key":"usr12345","_temperature":46.6})`

where the key is `usr12345` and value is `{"_key":"usr12345","_temperature":46.6}`

The `.print()` on the stream outputs the value correctly:

`(usr12345,{"_key":"usr12345","_temperature":46.6})`

But when I write the stream to Kafka the key becomes  `usr12345` (with a white space at the beginning) and the value `({"_key":"usr12345","_temperature":46.6}`

Notice the space at the beginning of the key and the left parenthesis at the beginning of the value.

Very strange. Why this might happen?

Here is the serialization code:

```
TypeInformation<String> resultType = TypeInformation.of(String.class);

KeyedSerializationSchema<Tuple2<String, String>> schema =
      new TypeInformationKeyValueSerializationSchema<>(resultType, resultType, env.getConfig());

FlinkKafkaProducer010.FlinkKafkaProducer010Configuration flinkKafkaProducerConfig = FlinkKafkaProducer010.writeToKafkaWithTimestamps(
      stream,   
      "topic",    
      schema,  
      kafkaProducerProperties);
```

Comment: What you have described is a bit weird, Have you tried creating a kafka sink and doing stream.addsink(kafkaSink)? May be that solves the issue?

Comment: @BiplobBiswas Well, I followed the instructions described in Flink Kafka documentation. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-producer According to that this is the right way to use the Java, Kafka 0.10+ which I'm using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TypeInformationKeyValueSerializationSchema` serializes data with Flink's custom serializers which means that the result has to be interpreted as binary data. Flink's String serializer writes the length of the String followed encoding all characters.

I would assume that you deserialize the Kafka topic with a plain String deserializer. For the key, the serialized length is interpreted as a whitespace character. For the value, the length is interpreted as `'('`.

Try to use a different serializer which serializes the key and value as plain strings or use a compatible deserializer.